# Can't create Trigger on MySql table within Google Cloud

Tags: mysql, triggers, google-cloud-sql, user-permissions

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_LocationType_Insert
BEFORE UPDATE ON LocationType
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.NAME = ''
```

Returns this error:

[HY000][1419] You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)

I know this is because even the root user "has all privileges except SUPER and FILE."
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/users

And I think that if I could "Set log_bin_trust_function_creators to 1" then it would work (this user does have CREATE TRIGGER permission). However, I don't see how to do that in the Google Cloud SQL console or from a sql statement.

How do you create a TRIGGER then within this environment?

Comment: Try to create with `DEFINER = user` or `DEFINER =  CURRENT_USER`   read (  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html  )

Comment: I tried CREATE
DEFINER = CURRENT_USER
TRIGGER... without any change.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This page described how to change MySQL configuration options for a Google Cloud instance: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags

> Select the instance to open its **Instance Overview** page.
>
> The database flags that have been set are listed under the **Database flags** section.

You have to use their UI to change global variables, because you can't use `SET GLOBAL` without SUPER privilege.

The `log_bin_trust_function_creators` option is listed among the supported configuration options you can change in the UI on the page I linked to above.

To read more about this error, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-logging.html